# Getting started with Fiware-CEP image on Fiware lab

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cep

I have launched the "cep-r3.3.3-img" image on the Fiware Lab.

I have allowed the port 8080 to be accessible from the exterior.

I can not access the proton interface visiting `http://<host>:8080/AuthoringTool/Main.html` in the browser.

I then tried following the examples provided [in the documentation](http://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/1_RoomsAndFloors/index.html). The linked examples has a run.sh, which makes a POST request to `http://<host>:8080/v1/admin/config`.

This endpoint (and all /v1/ endpoinds) is returning 404.

Is there anything else I need to perform to get the provided image to work as anticipated?

Comment: Note: this questions should be tagged with `fiware-cepheus`, but I can't create that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different FIWARE projects : Proton GEi and Cepheus GEi.

You can find the documentation related to Proton on the [catalog description](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/complex-event-processing-cep-proactive-technology-online/documentation).

The documentation you point to is the Cepheus one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification